# Reenable Setting app on rooted Galaxy S 4G

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, samsung-galaxy-s, terminal, application-manager

I need to command my  partially rooted Samsung Galaxy S 4G on KitKat 4.4.3, to simply re-enable the core app: `settings.apk` (a.k.a `com.android.settings`).

After flashing a ROM, I found no settings UI nor root capabilities. I see the APK is where it belongs, so I just need to enable it. How do I enable this app service (what terminal commands)?

APK location: `/system/priv-app/`

Data path: `/data/data/com.android.settings`

Comment: What do you mean by "partially rooted"?

Comment: Hello Andrew T.,hey buddy you keep editing posts to help which I thank you for, however I notice critical errors sometimes, such as this post was not about a galaxy S4, I posted about a Galaxy S 4G....its an entirely different animal...it's an S1 if anything...not an S4...please get this rectified and re-posted, as since your updates I haven't had any response.  Thanks Andrew T.

Comment: Fixed, sorry for the mistake since I'm not used to the abbreviation of SGS4G (though it'd be better if you could spell it out in the first place :) Also, you are very allowed to edit your own post to fix the mistake, and you can do it next time by clicking the [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/103511/edit) link on the bottom of your post :)

Comment: please just don't rename my device... I didn't say it was a galaxy s4...thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a root shell via ADB, try `pm enable com.android.settings`

Comment: ok ill try that.  ....and anyways for your question... i just did a rom flash same as usual which appears to have left traces of rooted artifacts but apps do not get the hand shake for root

Comment: and SuperSU apppears to have been updated so it just sticks or says it cant update...long story....i thank you for the suggestion

Comment: system responds after couple seconds with : "Killed"     help please